# About to graduate but feel my skill level is not sufficient to satisfy a future employer. How do I go about this?

Tags: professionalism, new-hires, graduate

I'm about to graduate with a bachelor's degree in Electronics - IT and I am currently doing my internship. I've always felt like I don't quite 'belong' in my year, often feeling that my skill level or knowledge is inferior compared to my peers.

With graduation in sights I want to know if anyone else felt this way before applying for a job, and if it in fact turned out to be true.

Comment: [I feel unqualified for my job - what is the right thing to do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/27910). [I feel that I'm too dumb for my job - what am I supposed to do in this position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/70029) [How do you kill imposter syndrome?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/56698) If there is evidence to suggest that you're good enough, but you don't believe it, you're probably suffering from [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome). If there's sufficient evidence to suggest you're not good enough... get better.

Comment: You're about to graduate - not everyone manages that or even tries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a long time in my life I thought that same thing. Everyone else is an expert, how can I, simple, inexperienced being be trusted with any important task. Over time I realized that nobody is perfect and quite often the quality delivered by others is not so great on a second look.

If your grades are OK and you pass, that means you are on par with the requirements. As long as you enjoy your field of work and get things done you will be fine.